# How to execute console app while installing an .msi which is created using WiX?

Tags: c#, wix

I have a main app, for which I have created an installer using WiX.
Currently I have a console application which will change the wallpaper of the system.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setup starting");
        SystemManager.SetWallpaper(Style.Stretched);
        SystemManager.ToggleDesktopIcons();
        SystemManager.SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates.AutoHide);
        AutoLogin.AutoLoginUser();
        Console.WriteLine("Setup Finished");
    }
```

This is what I am doing inside my console app.

I wish to add my console app as part of the setup which should be executed whilst installing.

What should I do to achieve this in WiX?

Comment: Note that launching executables is the least-integrated way to extend Windows Installer. (You can't log or interact with properties, other than reading those passed on the command line.) Prefer writing DLLs or equivalent when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html) in order to Run the Installed Application After Setup.

Comment: Its not about running idtalled app after installation. I have seperate exe which should ru while setup installs...